# Программа на с++ не работает: Необработанное исключение по адресу нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x000000A

Tags: c++

**Вот мой кода**

```
#ifndef _STCKP_H_
#define _STCKP1_H_
template <class Type>
class Stack
{
private:
    enum { MAX = 10};
    int stacksize;
    Type * items;
    int top;
public:
    explicit Stack(int ss = MAX);
    Stack(const Stack & st);
    ~Stack() {delete[] items;}
    bool isempty() { return top == 0; }
    bool isfull() { return top == stacksize; }
    bool push(const Type & item);
    bool pop(Type & item);
    Stack & operator=(const Stack & st);
};
template <class Type>
Stack<Type>::Stack(int ss) : stacksize(ss), top(0)
{
    items = new Type[stacksize];
}
template <class Type>
Stack<Type>::Stack(const Stack & st)
{
    stacksize = st.stacksize;
    top = st.top;
    items = new Type[stacksize];
    for (int i = 0; i < top; i++)
        items[i] = st.items[i];
}
template <class Type>
bool Stack<Type>::push(const Type & item)
{
    if (top < stacksize)
    {
        items[top++] = item;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
template <class Type>
bool Stack<Type>::pop(Type & item)
{
    if (top > 0)
    {
        item = items[-top];
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
template <class Type>
Stack<Type> & Stack<Type>::operator=(const Stack<Type> & st)
{
    if (this == &st)
        return *this;
    delete [] items;
    stacksize = st.stacksize;
    top = st.top;
    items = new Type[stacksize];
    for (int i = 0; i < top; i++)
        items[i] = st.items[i];
    return *this;
}
#endif


//stkoptr1.cpp - проверяет стек указателей


#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include "stckp1.h"
const int Stacksize = 4;
const int Num = 10;
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    cout << "Please enter stack size: ";
    int stacksize;
    cin >> stacksize;
    Stack <char *> st(stacksize);
    char * in[Num] =
    {
        "1: Hank Gilgamesh", "2: kikki Ishtar",
        "3: Betty Rocker", "4: Ian Flagranti",
        "5: Wolfgang Kibble", "6: Portia Koop",
        "7: Joy Almondo", "8: Xaverie Paprika",
        "9: Juan Moore", "10: Misha Mache"
    };
    char * out[Num];
    int processed = 0;
    int nextin = 0;
    while (processed < Num)
    {
        if (st.isempty())
            st.push(in[nextin + 1]);
        else if (st.isfull())
            st.pop(out[processed++]);
        else if (rand() % 2 && nextin < Num)
            st.push(in[nextin++]);
        else
            st.pop(out[processed++]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Num; i++)
        cout << out[i] << "\n";
    cout << "Bye\n";
    return 0;
}
```

[image: вот что выбивает при попытке определить массив]

Answer (score 1):

Допишем ваш код вот так:

```
while (processed < Num)
{
    if (st.isempty())
    {
        cout << "Push\n";
        st.push(in[nextin + 1]);
    }
    else if (st.isfull())
    {
        cout << "Pop\n";
        st.pop(out[processed++]);
    }
    else if (rand() % 2 && nextin < Num)
    {
        cout << "Push\n";
        st.push(in[nextin++]);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Pop\n";
        st.pop(out[processed++]);
    }
}
```

Запустим...

```
Please enter stack size: 6
Push
Pop
Push
Pop
Push
Push
Push
Pop
Push
Pop
Pop
Pop
Pop
Pop
Pop
Pop
```

Вам ничего не кажется странным? Например, что на 6 push'ей - 10 pop'ов? И что будет при `Pop` из пустого стека попадать в ваш массив `out`? чтобы потом быть выведенным?

Ну, а дальше разбирайтесь сами - отладчик или хотя бы отладочный вывод (как у меня) вам в помощь...